# Number of ways in which we can select non-intersecting couples from $n$ elements

Tags: combinatorics

While i was doing an Olympiad problem, i managed to reduce it to this one with a bijection, but now i don't know what to do:

> Suppose we have $n$ objects ordered in a line. In how many ways I can select a subset of non-intersecting couples composed by consecutive elements?

For example in the sequence $12345$ the answer is $7$:

$12\\ 23 \\ 34 \\ 45 \\ 12,34 \\ 12,45 \\ 23,45 $

There is also a generalization that may be helpful:

> Suppose we have $n$ objects ordered in a line. In how many ways I can select a subset $A$ (with $|A|\leq k$ where k is a given integer)  of non-intersecting $j$-ples composed by consecutive elements?

I would be happy even if you help me just with the first one. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you allow the empty subset? If so, the answer is $F_{n+1}$, the $(n+1)^{st}$ Fibonacci number. If not, then subtract one from this.

You can prove this by induction. If $a_n$ is the number of ways to select the couples (allowing the empty selection), then $a_n=a_{n-1}+ a_{n-2}$, which follows by considering whether or not the rightmost object, $n$, is in one of the chosen couples.

Comment: Stunning work :)

Comment: The comment about the empty subset is the subtle bit here.  :)  $F_5 = 7$ is not a Fibonacci number, after all.  And if one tries to write the recursion using $b_n$ which doesn't include the empty subset, one gets $b_n = b_{n-1} + (b_{n-2} \color{red}{+ 1})$ which is of course a shifted Fibonacci but may be less obvious.